# Using CUDA textures to store 2D surfaces

Tags: cuda, simulation, mesh

I am currently developing a 3D heat flow simulation on a 3D triangular mesh (basically any shape) with CUDA.

I was thinking of exploiting spatial locality by using CUDA textures or surfaces. Since I have a 3D mesh I thought that a 3D texture would be appropriate. After looking on different examples, however, I am not so sure anymore: **3D Textures are often used for volumes not for surfaces like in my case**.

*Can I use 3D textures for polygon meshes? Does it make sense? If not, are there other approaches or data structures in CUDA of use for my case?*

Answer (score 3):

Using 3D textures to store surface meshes is in fact a good idea. To better point this out, let me recall the clever approach in

[Octree Textures on the GPU, GPU Gems 2](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter37.html)

using 2D and 3D meshes to store an OctTree and to

1. Create an OctTree using a 3D texture;
2. Fastly traverse the OctTree by exploiting the filtering properties of the 3D texture;
3. Storing the surface polygons by a 2D texture.

**OCTTREE TRAVERSAL BY THE FILTERING FEATURES OF A 3D TEXTURE**

The tree is stored as an `8`-bit RGBA 3D texture mapped in the unit cube `[0,1]x[0,1]x[0,1]`, named as *indirection pool*. Each node of the tree is an *indirection grid*. Each child node is identified by the first three coordinates of the RGBA, while the fourth stores some other information, for example, if the node is a leaf or not or if it is empty.

Consider the QuadTree example reported in the paper (figure borrowed from the paper).

[image: Storage in texture memory of a QuadTree]

The `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` nodes (boxes) are stored as the texture elements `(0,0)`, `(1,0)`, `(2,0)` and `(3,0)`, respectively, containing, for a QuadTree, `4` elements, each element storing a link to the child node. In this way, any access to the tree can be done by exploiting the hardware filtering features of the texture memory, a possibility that is illustrated in the following figure:

[image]

and by the following code (it is written in Cg, but I'm sure it can be easily ported to CUDA):

**STORING THE TREE ELEMENTS BY A 2D TEXTURE**

The elements of the tree can be stored by the classical approach exploiting the `(u,v)` coordinates, see [UV mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping). The paper linked to above discusses a way to improve this method, but this is beyond the scope of this answer.